# invalid board header windows

Tags: c++, binary

I am trying to process a binary file generated by a PSI DRS4 for work. I tried this using a C++ code given in the src folder of the software used to run the board.

A friend of mine compiled and executed this code on his linux computer just fine. I wanted to adapt this code to windows. I went through the compilation step pretty easily but then when I try to execute it, it just crashes...

After some further investigation, what I understand is that the header(s) cannot be read properly (probably leading to the crash when they're supposed to be used later in the code)

I thus tried to read the file with HexEditor Neo and here is what I get: [screenshot binary file Hexeditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiNyF.png)

As you see the part after EHEADER becomes unreadable... Is  it normal? Has anyone faced this situation before ?

Comment: "as you see": no, we do not know how this file is supposed to look. What is the format of this file and of its header? If the format is documented somewhere, you could at least link to the description.

Comment: It is a .dat format actually.  for the header in itself I don't really know. I gave all the information I had here.

Comment: You might want to run this exe (or whatever) via cmd. I guess this way you will get to know the reason for crash.